# JavaScript - Replace a Function in a Plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using the head.js function to assist loading JS & CSS files in parallel.

I'm also using Google Minify and I've found a problem in the following function in head.js:

Head.js code: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headjs/1.0.3/head.load.js

```
function getExtension(url) {
    url = url || "";

    var items = url.split("?")[0].split(".");
    return items[items.length-1].toLowerCase();
}
```

This function is used to determine if a file is CSS - basically if it doens't return CSS its considered JS.

My minify files are used like this:

```
includes/min/?g=site_index_css
```

Therefore when these run through the getExtension the ? means they don't return CSS and therefore are treated as JS.

I declare the plugin as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/head.load.min.js"></script>
```

and use the following to use it:

```
<script>
  head.load("includes/min/?g=site_activity_css");
</script>
```

How can I replace the getExtension in head.js? I have seen other posts relating to this kind of function replacement but I'm still confused on how to do it.

thankyou - Note: I will send this question to the owner of head.js once working so he can update when he has time available.

---

this is how I'm trying it in the ... is this how I should add the code?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/head.load.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function getExtension(url) {
    url = url || "";

    var ext = '';
    if(ext = url.match(/(?<=&type=)[a-z]+/))
        return ext[0];

    var items = url.split("?")[0].split(".");
    return items[items.length-1].toLowerCase();
  }
</script>


<script>
  head.load("includes/min/?g=site_activity_css&type=css");
</script>
```

Below is the Head.JS GitHub URL for this issue - https://github.com/headjs/headjs/issues/287

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
function getExtension(url) {
    url = url || "";

    var ext = '';
    if(ext = url.match(/type=[a-z]+/i))
        return ext[0].substr(5).toLowerCase();

    var items = url.split("?")[0].split(".");
    return items[items.length-1].toLowerCase();
}
```

And load:

```
head.load("includes/min/?g=site_activity_css&type=css");
```

Comment: thx for your help. does this mean will I load a js file I should include the extra parameters too... eg: head.load("includes/min/?g=site_activity_js", null, 'js');?

Comment: doesn't seem to work - I get the original javascript include and then I do get a css entry but its not correctly formed.

Comment: New idea :P I'm not sure about compatibility, but works for me :P

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work - I've put how I'm adding the code into the bottom of original question - does that look correct?

Comment: Yes, but for compatibility use: `if(ext = url.match(/&type=[a-z]+/)) return ext[0].substr(5);`

Comment: still can't get it working... oh well... appreciate you help. Doesn't appear the function is being replaced... I tried to put an alert in there and it doesn't trigger...